# Use python 2.7 on Kaggle kernel

Tags: python, kaggle

I am new to Kaggle kernels, I tried using my code on the kernel.
The only issue I am facing is my script is in python 2.7, but kernel support 3.5.

Is  there any way, I can support python 2.7 on kernel?
Any links also would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, kernels only support Python 3.

ETA: If you're looking for a hosted notebook environment, I just checked and [Google Colab does support Python 2](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/unregistered.html), so I might check that out instead if you really need 2.7.